# where does the system store the variable referred by the closure

Tags: javascript

If a closure is returned in a outer function and that closure refers some variables defined in that outer function, is the outer function will be recycled after the return statement ?

And as the closure is still have access to the variables, where does the system store these variables ?

thanks!

Comment: I want to say in memory, but I don't think that's sufficient.

Comment: Any variable will get disposed when they it is no longer reachable by any 'path' starting from the global object, and that's the only rule. The time when it should occur is not specified. The way all data are stored is not specified also, but you shouldn't care unless you are writing your own javascript engine or tweaking an existing one.

Comment: just curious about where the engine will store these local variable defined in the outer function as seems the life cycle of these variable is not same as the outer function itself

Comment: The JavaScript standard doesn't specify where captured variables are stored or what happens to the outer function. Different engines may do things differently.

Answer (score 1):

Each closure will create new class/function finally
and each variable that referenced by the closure will be a one of its fields/properties 
so, no, won't be garbage collected
it will garbage collected when the instance of class/function of your closure has no reference

Comment: The outer object will be included in the execution context of the inner function(closure) when the inner function being called.

Comment: when you say  outer object , do you mean the outer function itself ?

Comment: Each function in JavaScript also contains all the variables in the containing function.  So even if the outer object gets garbage collected, the closure function still has those variables.  This is a nice explanation: http://www.smartik.net/2013/07/Closures-CSharp-vs-JS-Same-But-Different.html.

Answer (score -1):

i did not understand your question first now i am updating my answer.

**Explanation:-**
You can nest a function within a function. The nested (inner) function is private to its containing (outer) function. It also forms a **closure**.

**A closure** is an expression (typically a function) that can have free variables together with an environment that binds those variables (that "closes" the expression).

**Since a nested function is a closure**, this means that a nested function can "inherit" the arguments and variables of its containing function. In other words, the inner function contains the scope of the outer function.

**To summarize:**

The inner function can be accessed only from statements in the outer function.

The inner function forms a closure: the inner function can use the arguments and variables of the outer function, while the outer function cannot use the arguments and variables of the inner function.

The following example shows nested functions:

```
function addSquares(a,b) {
function square(x) {
  return x * x;
}
return square(a) + square(b);
}
a = addSquares(2,3); // returns 13
b = addSquares(3,4); // returns 25
c = addSquares(4,5); // returns 41
```

**Since the inner function forms a closure, you can call the outer function and specify arguments for both the outer and inner function:**

```
function outside(x) {
function inside(y) {
  return x + y;
}
return inside;
}
fn_inside = outside(3); 
result = fn_inside(5); // returns 8

result1 = outside(3)(5); // returns 8
```

**Preservation of variables**

**Notice how x is preserved when inside is returned.** A closure must preserve the arguments and variables in all scopes it references. Since each call provides potentially different arguments, a new closure is created for each call to outside. The memory can be freed only when the returned inside is no longer accessible.

This is not different from storing references in other objects, but is often less obvious because one does not set the references directly and cannot inspect them.

---

when a global variable is set, it's added to the window object!

```
var myValue;
function setValue()
{
myValue = "test";
}

function getValue()
{
alert(window.myValue); // yup, it's "test"
}
```

Comment: I am talking about not global variable, I am talking about local variable defined in the outer function and referred by the closure

Comment: you know every thing is an object in javascript, functions are also. and they all are bound in a way. you can view this hierarchy in firebug by opening dom window.

Comment: mozilla uses spider monkey as javascript engine . and you can visit here :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/Internals

Comment: @developerCK the problem is that OP wasn't talking about global variables. It's true that declaring a variable without var(or this) will make it become global, but what about declaring a variable with var, you just can have access to this kind of variables unless you've defined a closure. I think OP's question is about this kind of varibles.